# Implementing keyboard shortcuts in Angular apps

Tags: angularjs

I am currently using a directive to implement keyboard shortcuts in my angular app.
The directive called "keyCapture".
It is included in the body tag of my index page.

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl" key-capture>
```

This directive uses a mix of $broadcast and other methods to get things done.

```
angular.module('plunker').directive('keyCapture',['$state','$rootScope',function($state, $rootScope){
  var shortCutKeys = [];

  return {
    link: function(scope,element,attrs,controller){
      element.on('keydown',function(e){
        shortCutKeys.push(e.keyCode);
        if (shortCutKeys.length === 2){
           var key2 = shortCutKeys.pop();
          var key1 = shortCutKeys.pop();

            /*press g and 1 - navigate to a different state*/
          if (key1 === 71 && key2 == 49) {
            $state.transitionTo('option1');
          }  

          /*press g and 2  - navigate to a different state*/
          if (key1 === 71 && key2 == 50) {
            $state.transitionTo('option2');
          }

          /*press g and 3  - call a function */
          if (key1 === 71 && key2 == 51) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('option1-event1')
          }

          /*press g and 4  - call a function*/
          if (key1 === 71 && key2 == 52) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('option1-event2')
          }

        }
      })
    }

  };

}]);
```

The plnkr is available here:
http://plnkr.co/yqS3O3wGoiE00tPOzcLP

I am skeptical if this is the right way to implement keyboard shortcuts into a app. 
Anyone has a better idea of how to integrate keyboard shortcuts into a app.. kindly comment .. or event better.. explain with some code sample.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out [Angular Hotkeys](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-hotkeys/) ? Brad Green the project manager of Angular has mentioned how awesome it is a few times. Probably better than implementing yourself unless you're just trying to learn.

Comment: I hadn't heard of it.. but just checked it out.. Didn't quiet undertand how to use in for chanding routes.. I have created a plnkr for this ..http://plnkr.co/edit/SV24o4ZRB6UEXfGlt8F2    if you look at the config for 'option1' module.. the hotkeys don't work.. any clue why ?

Comment: Apart from this .. hotkeys seems to be buggy.. when creating hotkeys for t+c and c+c .. it would get confused and not perform the correct action